# Why would $_GET['a'] not be populated when $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] contains 'a=foo'?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

Working with this php script, invoked via fastcgi under nginx. Not using a php-specific fastcgi module, just invoking it like any other unix executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
echo 'Hello world'; echo "\n";
echo $_GET['a']; echo "\n";
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; echo "\n";
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "\n_GET\n";
while (list($var,$value) = each ($_GET)) {
    echo "$var => $value <br />\n";
}
?>
```

The script is called `api/example` under the document root. I send this request:

```
GET /api/example?a=foo HTTP/1.1
```

And get this response:

```
Hello world

a=foo
/api/example?a=foo
_GET
```

ie. php has initialised `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as expected -- which demonstrates the parameters are being passed through the nginx/fastcgi layer -- but `$_GET['a']` remains uninitialised and in fact the `$_GET` associative-array is completely empty? Why?

I'm running PHP 5.3.29. I tweaked `request_order` in php.ini to `ESGP` (from the default `GP`) to try and fix this but I don't think that's relevant -- aside from that it's a standard config.

Comment: what does your `location /` config look like in your nginx configuration?

Comment: Ok changing `#!/usr/bin/php` to `#!/usr/bin/php-cgi` does fix my problem, but the duplicate doesn't really address the [very specific] question or assist in understanding what php is doing.

As best as I can tell `php-cgi` runs with a different "SAPI" module, which has different side effects. But confusingly, emulating the cgi environment on the command-line doesn't work, eg:

`QUERY_STRING='a=foo' REQUEST_URI='/api/example?a=foo' php-cgi ./example` on the command-line results in the same symptoms as above.

Answer (score 0):

Get is used for http style requests, this looks to be run as a cli.
Look into $argv if you want to pass parameters with cli